# in morphia how to query and return a field based on two other integer fields are same or not

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have mongodb running and using morphia.
Having a Collection of `BatchData` Documents and need to filter out some field values.

This is the Entity:

```
@Entity
public class BatchData {

  @Id private ObjectId id;
  public int val1;
  public int val2;
  public String uuid;

}
```

If `val1` equals `val2` then the query should return `uuid`

This is as far as a get but ofcourse it does not work:

```
Query<BatchData> q = mongo.createQuery(BatchData.class).field("val1").equal("val2");
List<BatchData> entities = q.asList();
```

OR

```
Query<BatchData> q = mongo.createQuery(BatchData.class).field("val1").equal(BatchData.class.val2)
```

There can be one million or more `BatchData` Documents so i must only
return the `uuid` for performance reason.

Been reading the wiki and cannot understand or see a filter for two member fields
[Morphia wiki](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Query#Returning_Data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the performance is very important, you should look at map-reduce function. Unfortunately, morphia does not support this MongoDB feature, so you need to work with java mongo driver itself. See [example](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/unique_items_map_reduce/) and [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any neat way in Morphia to do this, but you can use the basic Java MongoDB library and use the Javascript-supporting $where operator.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject( "$where",  
   "function() { return this.val1 == this.val2 }" );
DBCollection fieldsCollection = db.getCollection("BatchData");
DBCursor cursor = fieldsCollection .find(query);
```

It's not super fast since it needs to unpack and scan each object and can't use indexes, but it will do what you want.

Comment: Haven't gotten to the BasicDBObject but now i know what that is, thank
Was thinking that what i wanted was a common problem with some basic morphia operator. Think it will be slow using the BasicDBObject if i have millions of of Documents. What about map-reduce is'n that some search algorithmic?

Comment: Morphia is just a user-friendly wrapper and it creates `DBObject`s which are sent via the same Java library. The reason this is slow is the work done inside the MongoDB server.